# How to update state in better way

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have cards which needs to be displayed in UI, I'm maintaining the properties of each card as following,

```
 this.state = {
 deck1Cards: [
        {
          selected: true,
          countRef: 'chAll',
          label: properties.all_label,
          clickEvent: this.handleClick,
          color: '#ffffff',
          textcolor: '#026FC5'
        },
        {
          selected: false,
          countRef: 'chQ',
          label: properties.optch_label,
          clickEvent: this.handleClickSec,
          color: '#ffffff',
          textcolor: '#026FC5'
        }
      ],
      deck2Cards: [
        {
          selected: false,
          countRef: 'linAll',
          label: properties.all_label,
          clickEvent: this.handleClickLink,
          color: '#ffffff',
          textcolor: '#026FC5'
        },
        {
          selected: false,
          countRef: 'linQ',
          label: properties.out_of_rangeLinks,
          clickEvent: this.handleClickLinkSec,
          color: '#ffffff',
          textcolor: '#026FC5'
        },
        {
          selected: false,
          countRef: 'linNodata',
          label: properties.no_dataLinks,
          clickEvent: this.handleClickLinkThird,
          color: '#ffffff',
          textcolor: '#026FC5'
        }
      ]
}
```

I'm Iterating through this array of Object and drawing the cards, each card as specific on click event methods, on click of it i need to changes the selected property as true,

Im doing it this way,

```
let ccard = [...this.state.deck1Cards]
      let lcard = [...this.state.deck2Cards]
      ccard[0].selected = true
      ccard[1].selected = false
      lcard[0].selected = false
      lcard[1].selected = false
      lcard[2].selected = false

      this.setState({
        deck1Cards: ccard,
        deck2Cards: lcard
      })
```

can you suggest a better way to update the selected property of the card object

Answer (score 0):

You don't need individual click events per card, use a common handler. To do that, you need to have a way of uniquely identifying the card via the click event, a common approach here is to store some metadata in the DOM itself e.g.

```
<div data-id="some-id" ... >
```

Then in the handler, you can use the `currentTarget` property of the event to inspect the DOM element

```
function handleCardClicked(e) {
  // extract the unique ID
  const cardId = e.currentTarget.dataset.id;
  // create common update function 
  const updateSelectedState = card => ({
    ...card,
    selected: card.someUnqiueProperty === cardId
  });
  // Apply update to both lists
  const deck1Cards = this.state.deck1Cards.map(updateSelectedState);
  const deck2Cards = this.state.deck2Cards.map(updateSelectedState);
  this.setState({ deck1Cards, deck2Cards });
}
```